# Inkscape like tool in Mac with latex rendering capabilities

Tags: image-editing, latex

I'm looking for some `Inkscape` "like" application for MacOS where you can insert latex text/symbols and modify your figures to some extent. Inkscape with Xquartz is not working out for me.

Comment: Is cost an issue and what system version are you running?

Comment: A good guide to asking software recommendations on site meta: [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation)

Comment: @jmh : Yes! I'm looking for a freeware. I'm running Mojave 10.14.6 on the MacPro (late 2013)

Comment: @ankii : Thanks for pointing this out! Would keep this in mind for the next time.

Comment: what do you need this app to do?  Are you designing charts or something like that?  Would a program like powerpoint work for some of what you want?

Comment: Macs come with an app Keynote which is like Powerpoint on steroids. Maybe you could paste your graphics into a Keynote file and use the equation editor to add formulas to your graphics. The equation editor uses Latex.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape is probably the best free option. I don't know of paid drawing tools that have LaTeX built in. [LaTeXiT](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) is great for generating LaTeX formatted math formulas.

Comment: Inkscape is rather buggy on Mac. I would try it on my linux machine then. Thanks anyway!